# Find maximum users in a cell of a matrix of size nxn

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I was solving this algorithm problem but i am unable to find the reference answer as provided. Any help or tip in solving this problem is appreciated.

The problem statement is as follows
In an area of size NxN each cell contains 1 at time T=0 where 1 represent one user.

```
Hence, at T= 0 and N = 5 the matrix is as below
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
Each cell is a user.
Now at time T =1,2,3 etc the position of each user changes.

if x(row)+y(col) = even
New x = (x+y)^2%N
New y = (x*y)%N

if x(row)+y(col) = odd
New x = (x+y)%N
New y = |x-y|%N
```

Find the maximum users at time T = 3
Reference, for N=5 and T= 3 Max users in a cell should be 8.

I have tried solving this problem but I always end up with 11 as my max if I move all the users and 6 if I move just 1 user every time.
Any tips where I might be going wrong in understanding or solving this problem is very much appreciated. Thank you.
Below is my code which I used for solving this problem
Its in C programming language. Thanks in advance.

```
int abs(int y, int x)
    {
     int temp = x - y;
     return temp > 0 ? temp : -temp;
    }

int new_x(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return (((x+y)*(x+y))%n);
 else
  return (x+y)%n;
}

int new_y(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return (x*y)%n;
 else
  return ((abs(x,y))%n);

}

void print_matrix(int *p, int n, int time)
{
    int i,j;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("%d\t",*((p+i*n)+j));
            sum += *((p+i*n)+j);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Sum = %d\t at T=%d\n",sum, time);
}


int main(void)
{
    int T = 3;
    int N = 5;
    int test_case,i,j,x,y,item, sum, val;
    int arr_initial[5][5];
    //====================================
    //For Time T=0 all elements are 1
    //====================================
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
                arr_initial[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        //=====================================
        printf("Initial Matrix at T0 time\n");
        print_matrix((int*)arr_initial, N, 0);
        printf("\n");
        //====================================
        //Now calculate the new position for Time T1,T2 & T3
        //====================================
        for(test_case =1; test_case<=T;test_case++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {//Get NewX and NewY for movement
                    x = new_x(i,j,N);
                    y = new_y(i,j,N);
                    if(x==i && y==j)
                        {
                        //No movement as initial and new position is same
                        }
                    else{
                        //There is a movement
                        item = arr_initial[i][j];
                        val = item -1;
                            if(val<0) 
                                {
                                //no item to move
                                }
                            else 
                                {
                                arr_initial[x][y] += arr_initial[i][j];
                                arr_initial[i][j] = 0;
                                }
                        }

                    }
                }
            //=======================================================
            printf("\n");
            printf("Matrix at Time T = %d\n",test_case);
            print_matrix((int*)arr_initial, N, test_case);
            printf("\n");
            }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `if((x+y)%2)`  is true when `x+y` is  odd

Comment: What is the constraint for N and M? the problem is when you updating user position, you update it directly to the same array, so, you can already modify an cell before reading and processing it, which lead to wrong answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing the mistakes. Restriction of N is 5<=N<=100 and 3<=T<=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task statement differs from the code - you say `(x*y)^2` but implement `(x+y)^2`. This solution works by building the next generation in a separate array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    char matrix[N][N], next[N][N];
    int x, y, t, x2, y2, max;
    memset(matrix, 1, sizeof(matrix));          // initialise matrix
    for(t=0; t<3; t++) {
        memset(next, 0, sizeof(next));          // clear next generation
        for (y=0; y<N; y++)
            for (x=0; x<N; x++) {
                if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                    x2 = ((x + y) * (x + y)) % N;
                    y2 = (x * y) % N;
                } else {
                    x2 = (x + y) % N;
                    y2 = abs(x - y) % N;
                }
                next[y2][x2] += matrix[y][x];
            }
        memcpy(matrix, next, sizeof(matrix));   // copy back
    }

    max = 0;
    for (y=0; y<N; y++) {                       // print matrix
        for (x=0; x<N; x++) {
            if (max < matrix[y][x])
                max = matrix[y][x];
            printf("%-3d", matrix[y][x]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf ("Max is %d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1  0  0  0  0
0  2  0  0  4
0  0  0  0  0
4  8  0  4  0
0  2  0  0  0
Max is 8
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You calculate if (x+y) is odd wrongly. If (x+y)%2 is true than x+y is odd. Therefore:

```
int new_x(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return (((x+y)*(x+y))%n);
 else
  return (x+y)%n;
}

int new_y(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return (x*y)%n;
 else
  return ((abs(x,y))%n);

}
```

should be changed to:

```
int new_x(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return (x+y)%n;
 else
  return (((x+y)*(x+y))%n);
}

int new_y(int x, int y, int n)
{
 if((x+y)%2)
  return ((abs(x,y))%n);
 else
  return (x*y)%n;
}
```

2) You change fields in array, that were possibly still not processed:

```
arr_initial[x][y] += arr_initial[i][j];
```

You need to use another matrix, initialized to 0, to track new values in it and copy changes back to original matrix at the end of each step.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing the mistake i will give it another try. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading the value from the array and the value might already be modified, which becomes the value for T + 1!

Thus, you need another array to keep track of the value for T. Here is the idea:

```
    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j ++)
            alter_arr[i][j] = current_arr[i][j];

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {//Get NewX and NewY for movement
            x = new_x(i,j,N);
            y = new_y(i,j,N);

            printf("%d, %d moved to %d, %d\n", i, j, x, y);
            if(x==i && y==j)
            {
                // no movement
            }
            else{
                //There is a movement
                item = current_arr[i][j];
                val = item -1;
                if(val<0) 
                {
                    //no item to move
                }
                else 
                {
                    alter_arr[x][y] += current_arr[i][j];
                    alter_arr[i][j] -= current_arr[i][j];
                }
            }

        }
    }

    int (*tmp)[5] = current_arr;
    current_arr = alter_arr;
    alter_arr = tmp;

    //=======================================================
    printf("\n");
    printf("Matrix at Time T = %d\n",test_case);
```

And change the if statement in your new_x and new_y function.

Below is the result, the max is 8 at T = 3:

```
Initial Matrix at T0 time
1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   
Sum = 25     at T=0


Matrix at Time T = 1
1   2   0   2   0   
2   2   0   4   2   
0   2   0   0   0   
0   2   0   2   0   
2   2   0   0   0   
Sum = 25     at T=1


Matrix at Time T = 2
1   0   0   4   0   
2   4   0   6   2   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   2   0   2   0   
0   2   0   0   0   
Sum = 25     at T=2


Matrix at Time T = 3
1   0   0   4   0   
0   2   0   8   2   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   4   0   
0   4   0   0   0   
Sum = 25     at T=3
```